# understanding std::is_base_of possible implementation from cppreference

Tags: c++, overloading, template-meta-programming, function-templates-overloading

Here we have `is_base_of` template implementation taken from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of#Possible_Implementation):

```
namespace details {
     template <typename B>
     std::true_type test_pre_ptr_convertible(const B*);      //1
     template <typename>
     std::false_type test_pre_ptr_convertible(const void*);  //2

     template <typename, typename>
     auto test_pre_is_base_of(...)->std::true_type;          //3
     template <typename B, typename D>
     auto test_pre_is_base_of(int) ->
         decltype(test_pre_ptr_convertible<B>(static_cast<D*>(nullptr))); 
 }

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
 struct is_base_of :
     std::integral_constant<
     bool,
     std::is_class<Base>::value&& std::is_class<Derived>::value&&
     decltype(details::test_pre_is_base_of<Base, Derived>(0))::value
     > { };
```

And some **private** inheritance:

```
class A {};
class B : A {};
```

`is_base_of<A,B>::value` gives true and declaration no. 3 is the best match. Declaration no. 1 fails as a candidate(was passed a pointer to object of private subclass) and declaration no. 2 is ignored. But Why? Isn't `void*` a good match for every pointer type? If declaration no. 3 was not provided the code wouldn't compile. My question is why declaration no. 3 needs to be provided for this code to compile successfully? Why declarations no. 1 and no. 2 aren't sufficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overload resolution ignores accessibility for the purpose of deciding which candidates are viable and for choosing the best candidate.

If `D` is a derived class of `B` (irregardless of accessibility), then `//1` is always viable and a better candidate for overload resolution than `//2` (which is also viable) and overload resolution will choose the former.

If `//1` is chosen as best candidate and `B` is not a public base of `D`, then the required implicit conversion on the argument will however fail because `B` is not an accessible base. But that is already after overload resolution was done. There will be no attempt to then fall back to the "second best" overload `//2`.

Since the call to `test_pre_ptr_convertible` is therefore invalid, the whole program would normally be ill-formed. However, the call here is in the return type of a function template and so SFINAE applies, meaning that the overload

```
template <typename B, typename D>
auto test_pre_is_base_of(int) ->
    decltype(test_pre_ptr_convertible<B>(static_cast<D*>(nullptr)));
```

is simply not viable for the call from `is_base_of` and the only other remaining overload for `test_pre_is_base_of` is `//3`, which is then chosen.